# wpf contextmenu open submenu on click

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, menuitem

I have a contextmenu in WPF with multiple submenu's. The default behavior is that if you hover over a menuitem with items below it, it will open the submenu. However, i'd like to change that so it won't open on hover, but on left-click.

I made a copy of the default template of a MenuItem. In this, i made a few changes:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <!-- some default template code -->
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="RightArrow" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
        </Trigger>

        <!-- my code to supress the opening of the submenu in mouseover -->
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsOpen" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="False"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This seemed to work at first. However, when i slowly move the mouse to another menuItem, it appears for a moment - likely some space where the 'IsMouseOver' isn't true, but the submenu still shows.

How can i suppress it completely - unless someone clicks on the menuItem?

Comment: Dumb question - why are you changing the default behavior? Menus are pretty widely understood as is... By making your app behave differently, users have to learn something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is caused by `TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen`, which automatically sets `IsOpen` to True, before the Trigger sets it back to False.

```
<Popup 
    Name="PART_Popup"
    Placement="Right"
    HorizontalOffset="-4" 
    IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    Focusable="False"
    PopupAnimation="Fade">
    <Border 
        ...
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Since you allready got things wired using a Click Event you can just set

```
IsOpen="False"
```

Another way of going around this, would be to set

```
IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}"
```

And setting the IsChecked properties each time a MenuItem gets Clicked.